# Один блок под несколько задач

Tags: jquery

Всех приветствую,сразу извиняюсь если  название заголовка не совпадает c моим   вопросом.

Так вот у меня вопрос можно сделать блок `div` под несколько задач,например есть три кнопки нажал на одну,в блоке `div` появилось `<h1>Hello world</h1>`,нажал на вторую,в том же блоке `div` появилось `<h1>hi</h1>` и т.д

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".mybutton").click(function() {
  var h = $("<h1></h1>");
  h.text($(this).data("text"));
  $(".output").html(h);
});
```

```css
.output {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="mybutton" data-text="Hello World!">Hello World</button>
<button type="button" class="mybutton" data-text="Hi!">Hi</button>
<button type="button" class="mybutton" data-text="Good Bye!">Good Bye</button>
<br/><br/>
<div class="output">
  <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
</div>
```